# Vue.js how to get what tag name used for component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

here is my app is using editItem component ,
and my question is  : how to get what tag used for the component
in this situation tag name is "editItem"

**App.vue** :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <editItem />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import editItem from './edit-item.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    editItem
  }
}
</script>
```

**edit-item.vue** :

```
<template>
<button @click="sayMyTagName"> what is my tag name </button>
</template>
<script>
export default {

  props: {

  },
  methods: {
  sayMyTagName:function() {
    console.log("my tag name is: ?");
  }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the TAG name where clicked? Like there has BUTTON tag.

Comment: @MdJeweleIslam no

Comment: which TAG are you referencing to here?

Comment: @Shreeraj <editItem />

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I am assuming that you are trying to get the components name inside the same component. To achieve that you can try updating your code to below given code in your **edit-item.vue** file:

```html
<template>
   <button @click="sayMyTagName"> what is my tag name </button>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'editItem',
  props: {
    // your props here
  },
  methods: {
     sayMyTagName() {
        console.log("My Tag Name is:", this.$options.name);
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

You need to give a `name: 'editItem'` to your `editItem` component/file. And then you can access it using `this.$options.name`